# The idea behind $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod p$ in the Miller-Rabin algorithm

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, primality-test

Trying to understand something about the Miller-Rabin algorithm.

What exactly is the implication of $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod n$? I understand that it can be rearranged to $(x+1)(x-1) \equiv 0 \pmod n$, implying that either $x \equiv 1 \pmod n$ and/or $x \equiv -1 \bmod n$.

But why does it matter if $n$ is prime or not here?

For example $9^2 \equiv 1 \pmod {10}$, and $(9-1)(9+1) \equiv 0 \pmod {10}$ is true since $9+1 \equiv 0 \pmod{10}$

Isn't this congruence true regardless of what $n$ is, assuming we set $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$? What exactly is the necessary condition for $n$ being prime and why isn't it true if $n$ is composite?

Comment: I think my answer was a little confusing before, so I've updated it if you wanna give it another read. I also included a wikipedia link. Feel  free to ask any questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we know that $a \cdot b \equiv 0 \pmod n$, we know that the $a \cdot b$ must be a multiple of $n$; in other words, the product $ab$ must contain (the prime factorization of) $n$. Now if $n$ is prime, the only way $ab$ will contain $n$ is if at least one of $a$ or $b$ contains $n$ in their prime factorizations. Therefore at least one of $a$ or $b$ has to be congruent to $0 \pmod n$.

---

If $n$ is composite ($n = pq$), then we could have $a = k_1 p$ and $b = k_2 q$. The product $ab = k_1 k_2pq$ is congruent to $0$ $\pmod n$, but as you can see, neither of $a$ nor $b$ are individually congruent to $0 \pmod n$.

The proprety we are discussing is called [Euclid's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma).

Comment: Does it make sense to use contraposition here? For example, "If $n$ is prime, then either $a$ or $b$ or possibly both of them are congruent to $0$ modulo $n$", reversed to "If neither $a$ nor $b$ is congruent to $0$ modulo $n$, then $n$ is not prime"?

Comment: @user436854 Yes you are right about the contrapositive. Sorry I do not know anything about the algorithm itself so I cannot answer that question.

Comment: Is it possible for $x \equiv 1 \pmod p$ and/or $x \equiv -1 \pmod p$ to always hold even if $p$ is composite? (does such a composite $p$ exist?)

Comment: @user436854 Such $p$'s do exist; consider $p = 6$. None of $x \equiv 0, 2, 3, 4$ are solutions to $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod p$

Comment: I mean the other way around: when $x$ is always $-1$ or $1$ mod $p$ but $p$ is composite.

Comment: @user436854 The following is how I understood your question. Let me know if I misunderstood it: "Is there a composite $p$ such that the only solutions to $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod p$ are $x \equiv \pm1$?" The answer to that question is "Yes, $p = 6$. We can see that $x \equiv 1, x \equiv -1 \equiv 5$ are solutions to $x^2 = 1 \pmod 6$ and none of $x \equiv 0, 2, 3, 4$ are solutions. So the only solutions to $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 6$ are $x \equiv 1$, $x \equiv 5 \equiv -1$.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. But if such numbers exist, then what is the purpose of prime $p$ vs non prime $p$ if they can both potentially result in $\pm 1$ solutions only?

Comment: @user436854 It is sometimes useful to have more restrictions. For example, let's say you are in the middle of a proof and have a number $x$. If you can show that $x$ satisfies $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod p$ where $p$ is prime, you just gained new information about $x$; you know for sure that it's $\pm1 \pmod p$. But if you show $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod p$ where $p$ is composite, you haven't gained as much new information. You know that $x$ *could* be $\equiv \pm1$, but it could also be $\equiv$ (something else)

Answer (score 2):

It matters if $n$ is a prime or not. Take $n=8$, for example. The equation $x^2-1=0\pmod8$ has *four* solutions, $x=1, x=3,x=5$ and $x=7$. In general for any polynomial $f(x)$ of degree $d$ with integer coefficients the congruence equation $f(x)\equiv0\pmod p$ cannot have more than $d$ solution for primes $p$.

Comment: But why is this true and why does it matter in this case? Is the idea behind $p$ prime to ensure that if $(x-1)(x+1) \equiv 0 \pmod p$ holds, then there are only two solutions to $x$ somehow? Is it ever possible for there to only be two solutions even if $p$ is not prime?

Comment: For primes there are exactly  two  solutions for  $x^2-1=\pmod n$, namely $x=1, n-1$.

Comment: So if $p$ is not prime, then does there always exist a solution to $x^2 - 1 = 0 \pmod p$ that isn't $1$ or $-1$?

Comment: @user436854 If $n$ is prime then $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is an integral domain (and a field) so that $(a-1)(a+1) = 0$ iff $a+1= 0$ or $a-1 = 0$. If  $\mathbb{Z}_n$  is not an integral domain then they may be more solutions.

Comment: @user1952009 But then does this mean if we keep testing $x$ and find that it's $1$ or $-1$ mod $p$, does this mean $p$ must be prime?